# Azure Storage NodeJS modify default timeout settings

Tags: node.js, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am wondering if its possible for me to change the default timeout settings for Azure Storage BlobService. From the documentation I can see that the default settings are:

- Calls to get a blob, get page ranges, or get a block list are permitted 2 minutes per megabyte to complete. If an operation is taking longer than 2 minutes per megabyte on average, it will time out.
- Calls to write a blob, write a block, or write a page are permitted 10 minutes per megabyte to complete. If an operation is taking longer than 10 minutes per megabyte on average, it will time out.

Looking through the source code I see that the BlobService.getServiceProperties and setServiceProperties are listed with these two parameters:

- @param {int}          [options.timeoutIntervalInMs]           The server timeout interval, in milliseconds, to use for the request.
- @param {int}          [options.maximumExecutionTimeInMs]      The maximum execution time, in milliseconds, across all potential retries, to use when making this request. The maximum execution time interval begins at the time that the client begins building the request. The maximum execution time is checked intermittently while performing requests, and before executing retries.

Are these two parameters equal to the items above?

Now when I try to use the getServiceProperties using the following code I am not given any information other than logging, metrics, and cors data. Which is what is said on the Github page

```
blobSvc.getServiceProperties(function(error, result, response) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log('Result: ', result);
        console.log('Response: ', response);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

Result:  { Logging:
   { Version: '1.0',
     Delete: false,
     Read: false,
     Write: false,
     RetentionPolicy: { Enabled: false } },
  HourMetrics:
   { Version: '1.0',
     Enabled: true,
     IncludeAPIs: true,
     RetentionPolicy: { Enabled: true, Days: 7 } },
  MinuteMetrics:
   { Version: '1.0',
     Enabled: false,
     RetentionPolicy: { Enabled: false } },
  Cors: {} }
Response:  { isSuccessful: true,
  statusCode: 200,
  body:
   { StorageServiceProperties:
      { Logging: [Object],
        HourMetrics: [Object],
        MinuteMetrics: [Object],
        Cors: '' } },
  headers:
   { 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
     'content-type': 'application/xml',
     server: 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
     'x-ms-request-id': '45a3cfeb-0001-0127-0cf7-0149a8000000',
     'x-ms-version': '2015-02-21',
     date: 'Thu, 08 Oct 2015 18:32:36 GMT',
     connection: 'close' },
  md5: undefined }
```

So really I guess I am confused on the mismatch between documentation and if it is even possible to modify any timeout settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample call with the timeout option is:

```
var options = { maximumExecutionTimeInMs: 1000 };
blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('mycontainer', 'myblob', 'test.txt', options, function(error, result, response) {
  if(!error) { 
    // file uploaded 
  } 
});
```

You might also want to check the APIs and their options at: http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html

Comment: Hmm.. this does seem to work for me... :(

Answer (score 2):

The timeout settings are not 'properties associated with the service', but instead they are 'properties associated with a call to the Storage Library'.  The timeoutIntervalInMs setting and the maximumExecutionTimeInMs setting are parameters that you can set on the 'options' object that can be passed in with pretty much every operation (including uploading and downloading blobs).  So, if you want to modify the timeouts for a given operation, just pass the desired setting on the 'options' object when you call into the library.

The 'timeoutIntervalInMs' is the timeout sent in a request to the Azure Storage service.  This is the amount of time that the service will spend attempting to fulfill the request before it times out.  This is the setting in the documentation you mentioned here - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179431.aspx
If a call into the Storage Client makes multiple HTTP(S) requests to the Storage Service, this value will be passed with each call.

The 'maximumExecutionTimeInMs' is a client timeout.  This is tracked by the Storage Client across all Storage Requests made from that single API call.  For example, if you have retries configured in the client, this value will be checked before every potential retry, and the retry will not continue if more than the 'maximumExecutionTimeInMs' has elapsed since the start of the first request.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: What you posted makes sense apart from the options object that I can passed with each operation.  Would a sample call be blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('mycontainer', 'myblob', 'test.txt', options, function(error, result, response){
  if(!error){
    // file uploaded
  }
});?